# How to do this repainting logic in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, iteration, element

I have a div structure like the below,

```
<div id-"itemsRows">
  <ul id="row1">
          <input type="hidden" id="hfId" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfOrd" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDate" value="3" />
       <li class="popup"> <div id="p1"></div> <div id="p2"></div></li>
  </ul>
 <ul id="row2">
       <input type="hidden" id="hfId" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfOrd" value="5" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDate" value="6" />
       <li class="popup"> <div id="p2"></div> <div id="p2"></div> </li>
  </ul>
 <ul id="row3">
       <input type="hidden" id="hfId" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfOrd" value="3" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDate" value="4" />
       <li class="popup"> <div id="p3"></div> <div id="p3"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now i have a html got via ajax call which looks like this,

```
<ul id="ajaxrows">
<li>
  <input type="hidden" id="hfId" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfOrd" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfDate" value="3" />
  <div id="p11"></div> <div id="p12"></div>
</li>
<ul>
<ul id="ajaxrows">
<li>
      <input type="hidden" id="hfId" value="4" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfOrd" value="5" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hfDate" value="6" />
  <div id="p22"></div> <div id="p32"></div>
</li>
<ul>
```

Now i have to compare these two structures and match all the hiddenfield values. If all the three matches i have to replace the two divs inside the UL row1 with the divs from ajaxrows.. Any idea how this can be done in jquery?

Comment: please consider to post your own attempt, if any...

Comment: I hope you copy-pasted that and the ID's are not actually the same over and over again. My idea would be using `index` from the elements and compare the values

Comment: @spokey just for the understanding i am using index only.. Can you suggest a solution for this scenario...

Comment: will the value always be numbers?

Comment: Number of inputs in each block will be same in the html and from ajax result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a start

```
$('#itemsRows ul').each(function () { // go thru row uls
    var $this = $(this);

    var rows_arr = $(this).find('input').map(function () { // create an array with the input
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $('#wrap-ajax ul').each(function () { // I wrapped this in a div to better loop it
        var ajx_arr = $(this).find('input').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        if (rows_arr.toString() === ajx_arr.toString()) { // lazy meh way to compare arrays
            console.log(rows_arr, ajx_arr);
            $(this).find('div').appendTo($this.find('li.popup').empty()); // delete the old and put the new
        }

    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ac2F2/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that number blocks are same and the number of inputs in each block has same count.

```
 $($("#itemsRows ul")).each(function( index ){   
        var ajaxResult = $($("#ajaxrows li"))[index];
        var count =0;
        $($(this).find("input")).each(function( index2 ){
            var res = $(ajaxResult).find("input")[index2];
            if($(this).val() ==  $(res).val()){
                count++;
            }
        });


        var ajaxResultDivs = $($("#ajaxrows li")[index]).find("div");
        if(count == $(this).find("input").length){
             $($(this).find("div")).each(function( index ){   
               $(this).replaceWith($(ajaxResultDivs));              
            });
        }                        

    });

console.log($("#itemsRows"));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/xDLRv/2/)